# GJK Collision False-Positive in Java

Tags: java, 3d, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to implement 3D GJK collision using JavaFx. It works when the colliders are actually colliding, and if the colliders are far apart from each other, yet delivers false positives when the colliders are nearby in specific orientation. This leads me to believe its an issue with the simplex, yet I am unable to find the issue. Can someone help me?

Here is my code. The collider class only holds an array of points, and I double checked to make sure the points were convex. I can post them if needed.

```
    private static final double EPILSON = 0;

static private Point3D findSuppPoint(Collider_3d a, Collider_3d b, Point3D dir) {
    return a.findExtrema(dir).subtract(b.findExtrema(dir.multiply(-1)));
}

public static boolean Gilbert_Johnson_Keerthi_Collision(Collider_3d a, Collider_3d b) {
    Point3D dir = new Point3D(0,0,1);
    Point3D currPoint = findSuppPoint(a,b,dir);
    ArrayList<Point3D> simplex = new ArrayList<Point3D>();
    simplex.add(currPoint);
    
    dir = currPoint.multiply(-1); // find point to origin
    
    
    while(true) {
        currPoint = findSuppPoint(a,b,dir);
        if(currPoint.dotProduct(dir) < EPILSON) {
            return false;
        }
        simplex.add(currPoint);
        dir = calcSimplex(simplex, dir);
        if(dir == null){
            return true;
        }
        
        
    }
}

static private Point3D calcSimplex(ArrayList<Point3D> s, Point3D dir) {
    if(s.size() == 2) {
        return nextDir(s);
    }else if(s.size() == 3) {
        return triSimplex(s, dir);
    }else if(s.size() == 4){
        return tetraSimplex(s, dir);
    }
    return dir; // should never happen
}

static private Point3D tetraSimplex(ArrayList<Point3D> s, Point3D dir) {
    Point3D AB = s.get(2).subtract(s.get(3));
    Point3D AC = s.get(1).subtract(s.get(3));
    Point3D AD = s.get(0).subtract(s.get(3));
    Point3D AO = s.get(3).multiply(-1);
    
    
    Point3D ABCDir = AB.crossProduct(AC);
    Point3D ADBDir = AC.crossProduct(AD);
    Point3D ACDDir = AD.crossProduct(AB);
    
    if(ABCDir.dotProduct(AD) > 0) {
        ABCDir = ABCDir.multiply(-1);
    }else if(ADBDir.dotProduct(AC) > 0) {
        ADBDir = ADBDir.multiply(-1);
    }else if(ACDDir.dotProduct(AB) > 0) {
        ACDDir = ACDDir.multiply(-1);
    }
    
    if(ABCDir.dotProduct(AO) > 0) {
        s.remove(0);
        return ABCDir;
    }else if(ADBDir.dotProduct(AO) > 0) {
        s.remove(1);
        return ADBDir;
    }else if(ACDDir.dotProduct(AO) > 0) {
        s.remove(2);
        return ACDDir;
    }
    System.out.println("AHHHH");
    return null;
}



static private Point3D triSimplex(ArrayList<Point3D> s, Point3D dir) {
    Point3D AB = s.get(1).subtract(s.get(2));
    Point3D AC = s.get(0).subtract(s.get(2));
    Point3D AO = s.get(2).multiply(-1);
    Point3D ABDir = (AC.crossProduct(AB)).crossProduct(AB);
    Point3D ACDir = (AB.crossProduct(AC)).crossProduct(AC);
    if(ABDir.dotProduct(AO) > 0) {
        s.remove(0);
        return ABDir;
    }else if(ACDir.dotProduct(AO) > 0) {
        s.remove(1);
        return ACDir;
    }
    return dir;
}

static private Point3D nextDir(ArrayList<Point3D> s) {
    Point3D AB = s.get(0).subtract(s.get(1));
    Point3D AO = s.get(1).multiply(-1);
    return (AB.crossProduct(AO)).crossProduct(AB);
    
}
```